# How to check two dates if dates between them exists or not with the database value

Tags: php

Example: 
i have to check these dates:-> from=`15 March 2013`  & `15 April 2013`  between the following dates  whether any days falls in between these two date or not.

### following data from db table

```
#       from date            to-date
-----------------------------------------
1     01 April 2013         30 April 2013   //here we will find as falling
2     01 May 2013           15 May 2013   
3     01 June 2013          20 June 2013
```

I know only the below techniques to do for a single date checking but i don't know how to compare for 2 days.

```
// set some example data
$referenceDate = '01 April 2013';
$fromDate = '01 January 2013';
$toDate = '01 June 2013';

// convert dates to timestamps (strings to integers)
$referenceTimestamp = strtotime( $referenceDate );
$fromTimestamp = strtotime( $fromDate );
$toTimestamp = strtotime( $toDate );

// isBetween is Boolean TRUE if reference date is greater or equal fromDate and smaller or       
  equal toDate
$isBetween = $referenceTimestamp >= $fromTimestamp and $referenceTimestamp <= $toTimestamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use *BETWEEN* if you're using a mysql database.

```
SELECT * FROM `dt_tb` WHERE year( date_column ) between 2004 and 2005
```

"date_column" is a date field, "year" means that it's only looking to the years. For a full date check, try this:

```
SELECT * from `dt_tb` WHERE date_column BETWEEN "2001-01-05" AND"2001-01-10";
```

Comment: you are not clear with my doubt. Please read my question once more